# Problem with 'cdqa': cannot import name 'TemporaryResourcesManager' from 'joblib._memmapping_reducer'

Tags: python, nlp, joblib

I am trying to use the cdqa library (https://github.com/cdqa-suite/cdQA). I cloned the GitHub repository using "git clone" and changed the specified versions of pandas and pytorch in the "requirements.txt" file for my versions (because I had problems installing the specific versions requested for these two libraries and, according to the "issues" in that github repository, several people managed to install cdqa by changing the versions in "requirements.txt"). Then, I used:

```
cd cdQA
pip install -e .
```

Now, I'm running the example that is in that library's GitHub repository:

```
import pandas as pd
from ast import literal_eval

from cdqa.utils.filters import filter_paragraphs
from cdqa.utils.download import download_model, download_bnpp_data
from cdqa.pipeline.cdqa_sklearn import QAPipeline
#from cdqa.pipeline import QAPipeline

# Download data and models
download_bnpp_data(dir='./data')
download_model(model='bert-squad_1.1', dir='./Models')

# Loading data and filtering / preprocessing the documents
df = pd.read_csv('data/bnpp_newsroom-v1.1.csv', converters={'paragraphs': literal_eval})
df = filter_paragraphs(df)

# Loading QAPipeline with CPU version of BERT Reader pretrained on SQuAD 1.1
cdqa_pipeline = QAPipeline(reader='Models/bert_qa.joblib')
```

but it returns the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-596fa5ffc73b> in <module>
      4 from cdqa.utils.filters import filter_paragraphs
      5 from cdqa.utils.download import download_model, download_bnpp_data
----> 6 from cdqa.pipeline.cdqa_sklearn import QAPipeline
      7 #from cdqa.pipeline import QAPipeline
      8 

~/Documents/GIT/QA/cdQA/cdqa/pipeline/__init__.py in <module>
----> 1 from .cdqa_sklearn import QAPipeline
      2 
      3 __all__ = ["QAPipeline"]

~/Documentos/Morning_Star_Consulting/GIT/QA/cdQA/cdqa/pipeline/cdqa_sklearn.py in <module>
----> 1 import joblib
      2 import warnings
      3 
      4 import pandas as pd
      5 import numpy as np

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/__init__.py in <module>
    118 from .numpy_pickle import load
    119 from .compressor import register_compressor
--> 120 from .parallel import Parallel
    121 from .parallel import delayed
    122 from .parallel import cpu_count

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py in <module>
     24 from .logger import Logger, short_format_time
     25 from .disk import memstr_to_bytes
---> 26 from ._parallel_backends import (FallbackToBackend, MultiprocessingBackend,
     27                                  ThreadingBackend, SequentialBackend,
     28                                  LokyBackend)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/_parallel_backends.py in <module>
     17     from .pool import MemmappingPool
     18     from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
---> 19     from .executor import get_memmapping_executor
     20 
     21     # Compat between concurrent.futures and multiprocessing TimeoutError

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/executor.py in <module>
     10 
     11 from ._memmapping_reducer import get_memmapping_reducers
---> 12 from ._memmapping_reducer import TemporaryResourcesManager
     13 from .externals.loky.reusable_executor import _ReusablePoolExecutor
     14 

ImportError: cannot import name 'TemporaryResourcesManager' from 'joblib._memmapping_reducer' (/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/_memmapping_reducer.py)
```

How could I fix that error, which I think is related to joblib? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

make sure your python version is >=3.8.0

modify this file

python3.8/site-packages/joblib/externals/cloudpickle/cloudpickle.py

line 135

change to

co.co_kwonlyargcount,

0,

co.co_nlocals,

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).